# For what reason these two appels write so different?

Tags: function, strtok

A code in C++ displays the words in the sentence: "Ana are mere." Here, space character is separator. For what I need to write p=strtok(p," "); before while() and p=strtok(NULL," "); in while()? Why I can't reverse them?

Comment: #include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s[12],*p;
    s="Ana are mere."
    p=strtok(p," ");
    while(p!=0)
    {
       cout<<p<<endl;
       p=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your question to include the above code so it can be pretty-formated.